# Resetting php array

Tags: php

I am trying to solve a problem where I have an array of days like this

```
$days = array ('Monday','Tuesday ','Wednesday ','Thursday ','friday');
```

I want to print them out 66 times in a loop, and everytime it gets to Friday the array reset itself and print Monday.  I tried this:

`$days = current($days); 

while($days <= 66){

echo  $days; 

next ($days); 

if (end ($days)){

reset($days); 

}`

Comment: please post the code used to print the array 66 times...

Comment: what is your current and expected output

Comment: you can use some loop

Comment: use modulo in loop? Or For i=0 to i<60 foreach $days print...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$days = array ('Monday','Tuesday ','Wednesday ','Thursday ','friday');

for($i=0 ; $i<66; $i++ ){
    foreach ($days as $row){
        echo $row;
        echo '</br>';
    }
}
```

You just need 2 loops. 1 for the day array and one for the times you want to repeat.

Comment: From all the answers, that's the most correct way. Nothing more is needed. Expect OP doesn't want the whole array to get outputed 66 times, but there should be 66 days starting from Monday, going to Friday and starting again from Monday. But only OP knows that answer..

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = 0;
for ($i=1;$i<=66;$i++){
    print_r($days[$num]);
    $num = ($num ==5) ? 0 : num +1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have two counter variables, and do something like this.

```
$a = 0;
$days = array('Monday','Tuesday ','Wednesday ','Thursday ','friday');

for ($i = 0; $i < 65; $i++) {
    print($days[$a]);
    $a++;
    if ($a == sizeof($days)) {
        $a = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fantastic opportunity to use [the extensive range of Iterator classes available in the SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php)

```
<?php
$days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'];

$infinite = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($days));

foreach ( new LimitIterator($infinite, 0, 66) as $value ) {
    echo $value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

See https://eval.in/935594